# Convert flat xml string to tree structure

Tags: xml, xslt, flat

I have a flat xml string:    `<XML><Test><Result>123</Result></Test></XML>`

How can I use xslt convert this string to standard xml structure like this:

```
<XML>
 <Test>
   <Result>123</Result>
 </Test>
</XML>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with the [`xsl:output`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#output) element's `indent` attribute set to "yes":

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```